# How to send class field by reference in function in Dart (actually in Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have class:

```
class User {
  String firstName = '';
  String lastName = '';
  String email = '';
  String description = '';
}
```

and in Flutter I have this:

```
    final _user = User();
    ...
    ...
    ...
    var formFields = [
      TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(isDense: true, hintText: 'First Name, no middle initial'),
        onSaved: (val) => setState(() => _user.firstName = val.toString()),
        validator: (String? val) => (val == null || val.isEmpty) ? '* First Name required' : null,
      ),
      ...
      ...
      ...
    ]
```

and this list of 4 TextFormFields looks ugly for me, so I want to create a function which will replace this TextFormFields, smth. like this:

```
    TextFormField formField({
      required String field,
      String hint = '',
      String error = '',
    }) {
      return TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(isDense: true, hintText: hint),
        onSaved: (val) => setState(() => field = val.toString()),
        validator: (String? val) => (val == null || val.isEmpty) ? '* $error' : null,
      );
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    var formFields = [
      formField(
        field: _user.firstName,
        hint: 'First Name, no middle initial',
        error: 'First Name required',
      ),
      ...
      ...
      ...
    ]
```

but in this case I cannot save firstName value in class.

Sure, must be correct way how to write this in more nice way because I know that Flutter send primitive types by value, but maybe are some workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

right now I see only one way how to do it:

```
    TextFormField formField({
      required void Function(String) fn,
      String hint = '',
      String error = '',
      bool disable = false,
    }) {
      return TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(isDense: true, hintText: hint),
        onSaved: (val) => setState(() => fn(val.toString())),
        validator: (String? val) {
          return (disable)
              ? null
              : (val == null || val.isEmpty)
                  ? '* $error'
                  : null;
        },
      );
    }

    var formFields = [
      formField(
        fn: (v) => _user.firstName = v,
        hint: 'first name',
        error: 'first name required',
      ),
      ...
      ...
      ...
    ]
```

but it also not so nice...

Comment: This would be the way to do it until there's [syntax for setter tear-offs](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/691).